# How to remove the last line from a variable in bash or sh?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a variable that has few lines. I would like to remove the last line from the contents of the variable. I searched the internet but all the links talk about removing the last line from a file.
Here is the content of my variable

```
$echo $var
$select key from table_test
UNION ALL
select fob from table_test
UNION ALL
select cal from table_test
UNION ALL
select rot from table_test
UNION ALL
$
```

I would like to get rid of UNION ALL appearing in the last line alone.

Comment: `echo $var` would not produce the output you show, although `echo "$var"` would.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sed` can do it the same way it would do it from a file :

```
> echo "$var" | sed '$d'
```

EDIT : `$` represents the last line of the file, and `d` deletes it.
See [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.1) for details

Comment: May be: `var=$(sed '$d' <<< "$var")`

Comment: I suspect your variable to be on only one line. Does `echo "$var"  | wc -l` return 1 ?

Comment: Yes. It returns 1.

Comment: Ok..I have managed to fix it. I have added this command
`selectstmt=$(echo -e $var)`
and then executed this command
`echo "$var"| sed '$d'`

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $var | head -n -1
```

Get all but the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to cut off the last line.

```
Count=$(echo "$Var" | wc -l)
echo "$Var" | head -n $(($Count -1))
```

`head -n $(($Count -1))` describes how many rows you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
last_line=`echo "${str##*$'\n'}"` # "${str##*$'\n'}" value gives the last line for 'str'
str=${str%$last_line} # subtract last line from 'str'
echo "${str}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash way:

```
echo "${var%$'\n'*}"
```

This prints `$var` with all characters incl. and after the last LF removed.